# Is there any such feature like "user-pages"?

Tags: support

There is a user-page for every Stack Exchange site, but is there something like user-*talk*-page?

If such a page exists, that would help to place comments which are off-topic, yet important. Moderators could be deliver some important messages, guidelines, etc., there.

Comment: Moderators can already send private messages to users, which are visible to all other moderators as well. And no need for such a thing for ordinary users, since Stack Exchange is not a social forum.

Comment: Thanks for informing moderators can send off-topic yet valuable information through private message. So this feature already exists and I'm going to delete this question immediately.

Comment: Oh no another user advising me not to delete this question since it has an upvoted answer. so instead I'm modifying the question

Comment: suggested tag inquiry

Comment: Maybe you should state in the question what this is modelled on (Wikipedia) so folks don't think it is like a social network.

Comment: Yes Wikipedia was in my mind.

Answer (score 8):

There is such a place already: meta.

On meta moderators and other users can request support, start a discussion or do a feature request. Moderators can pin such questions on the featured section so those posts are visible on the main site.

The spam protection mechanism is there already too: you need 5 reputation to ask a question on meta.

For private communication between moderators and users there is a distinct system in place that users can reach through the *Contact us* page in the footer.

Moderators can also change some sections in the help center to explain some site-specific rules.

For private communication between users, there is no place, and shouldn't be. Stack Exchange is not a social network and it will never be.

Comment: I think you missed the OP's point here (or maybe I missed), as far as I can see they talk about "talk" page per user, just per site.

Comment: It seems users should be able to comment too so I think this is somewhat like meta.

Comment: I didn't told that. Meta is one general page. I've told about individual user's talk page. For example, when an user want to tell ME, "why you've chosen such a username", or "you should improve this and this things in your any-question", then the users forced to write such "off-topic" yet important comments below my question or answer. That could be done in a separate talk-page for me.

Comment: That is a bad idea since Stack Exchange is not a social network and it will never be.

Comment: Maybe I'm not aware about such a feature on meta.

Comment: @AlwaysConfused there were quite a few such ideas, all deleted as far as I can tell due to being downvoted without an upvoted answer. (Or maybe I missed one.)

Comment: I did not meant about social networking. Wikipedia also provides an user-talk-page. Wikipedia is no social media.

Comment: And "why did you choose that user name" is useful why exactly?

Comment: One minute. Probably here it could be done using the chat room feature. Though never I've received anysuch off-topic comments as separate chat. I'm also yet not well accustomed with chat room feature because I rarely need it. If chat room feature can serve this, then I'll soon delete this question.

Comment: Chat is another good option. You can't delete this question since it has an upvoted answer, so why not put another answer in yourself? It will have my vote :)

Comment: Hmm when this question was asked to me, with a name-change request, I was in doubt that is there anything offensive in my pen-name? so I thought I should give an explanation. though it was far off-topic , I had to reply it there in. I also copied and pasted in all of my user-pages.

Answer (score 5):

As per request of user @PatrickHofman I'm posting a summary from discussion by other users.

1. Moderators can send private message. (Courtesy: User @ShadowWizard)
2. Chat could be used for any such off-topic comment. But since it is NOT a social networking site, use of chat for such purpose is of negligible importance for non-moderators.